# How to roll back to 14.04 intel drivers on 14.10?

Tags: drivers, 14.10

I installed 14.10 on my Lenovo x201 with Intel graphics card, and the performance has dropped significantly.  Pressing the 'search' button on launchpad is extremely slow and performance in general is choppy.

I want to roll back my video drivers to the ones used in 14.04 LTE, how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Several solutions: (in order from best to worst)

1. When booting go into the grub menu, advanced options and boot into the previous kernel  that has the driver version you want and make this the default until your bug report is in the "released" state.
2. Restore your system backup of 14.04 LTS (Long Time Support, remember?  More stable, less problems, ... )
3. Have a look at http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/intel_linux_graphics

   I use xorg/edgers from the same site and you'll have the latest and greatest drivers (with the possibility to roll back to earlier versions)
4. Manually download and install the 14.04 deb package and manually blacklist your 14.10 drivers.